# Add a date field to a Google contact without year

Tags: google-contacts

Is there a way to add a field like "Anniversary" to a Google contact *without* specifying the year? If I try to save while leaving the year blank, I get an error message:

> "Please enter a month, day and year for dates."

Comment: Not sure how you're coming up with this problem. Been testing and works fine without the year.

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me too.

Comment: I encounter the problem mentioned in the standalone contacts manager at http://www.google.com/contacts. If I try typing a date without the year in the integrated contact manager (with gmail), I get a little warning icon saying "We don't recognize this date".

Comment: To clarify, I want it to be added as a "date", like birthday, so that it shows up under Google Calendar as well. Not as a custom field.

Comment: This occurs to me with Chrome (aah! the irony), but not with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible in the newer version of Google Contacts, while in the old one you could, but without be able to changing the type of the event:

[image: data without year in google contacts]

In the newer version you're getting this error no matter how hard you try all the different formats of a date without a year: `Sorry, we don't recognize this date.`

Answer (score 0):

Just write `month date` for example you can see on image below. I open that date to my Google Calendar, it's worked so well.

[image: add birthday to Google Calendar]